# UILabel resizing on scrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have UILabel which has no height constraint set. The problem is that the label actually sets its height according to content. But scrollView doesn't let me go down, to the end of the text. Instead, takes me to a certain portion of that view or UILabel.

It can be seen in action in the link down below (Dropbox link - short video): [video link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmfaa76bj2x69sa/ScreenRecording_04-21-2018%2000-56-21.MP4?dl=0)

You can also see how it is structured in the storyboard below:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Hope it's working for you.

```
self.ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: BodyLabel.frame.origin.x, y: 
 BodyLabel.frame.origin.y, width: self.BodyLabel.frame.size.width, 
 height: self.BodyLabel.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but this doesn't seem to be working for me. I've tried to get rid of the auto-layout constraints and set them again but no luck. Any other idea?